# Put specific values in specific table cells from database. (Razor - html)

Tags: c#, html, sql, razor

```
<table class="prTable">
    <tr>
        <th>Exercise</th>
        <th>1</th>
        <th>2</th>
        <th>3</th>
        <th>4</th>
        <th>5</th>
        <th>6</th>
        <th>7</th>
        <th>8</th>
        <th>9</th>
        <th>10</th>
        <th>11</th>
        <th>12</th>
    </tr>

    @for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
    {
        <tr class="prTableRow">
        @if (i == 1)
        {
            <td class="prExerVariNameTD">Squat</td>
        }
        else if (i == 2)
        {
            <td class="prExerVariNameTD">Benchpress</td>
        }
        else
        {
            <td class="prExerVariNameTD">Deadlift</td>
        }
        @for (var ii = 1; ii <= 12; ii++)
        {
            var getPR = "SELECT top 1 kg, rep, date FROM Test WHERE exerVariName LIKE '%Comp%' AND exercise = @0 AND rep = @1 order by kg desc";
            db.Execute(getPR, i, ii);

            foreach (var get in db.Query(getPR, i, ii))
            {
                DateTime Date = get.Date;
                var finalDate = Date.ToString("MMM d, yyyy");
                var weight = get.kg + "kg";
                var reps = "x " + get.rep;

                <td class="prTableCell" title="@finalDate">@weight @reps</td>
            }
        }
        </tr>

    }
</table>
```

So, in my database I have a bunch of data, based on training and each row has a exerise name, multiple can have the same, all rows also have weight data and amount of repetitions done on it. What this does is that it checks each exercise name and selects the highest weight done on that exercise name for 1 repetition, then 2 and so on till 12. So it will show me the best result I have done for each repetition for each exercise name in a table layout like in the picture below

[image]

however, there aren't always data for each repetition for all exercises is the database, so some numbers doesnt show as you can see in the picture, the squat row goes 1,2,3,5,6,10,12, so a few are missing, and I want each number to be under each corresponding number that is in the table header, so 5 will be located under 5 and so on, the way I would like to solve this is to put 0kg in the cells that has no data, so for example on the squat row, there is no data for number 4, I would like to put 0kg there which would push the 5 one forward one cell and it would end up under number 5, and so on for all so that they are all on the correct place.

So, for all repetition numbers that isn't in the database I would like to put 0. Does this even make sense?

EDIT:
Database picture

[image]

Comment: Can you store the results of db.Query(getPR, i, ii) in one variable and check if you are getting 12 excercises? from the above mentioned code i am thinking that your query is restricting the number of records

Comment: ye it doens't do anything at all if the number doesnt exist, it just skips to the next number! @NaveenKN

Comment: can i see how the data is stored in the database? please edit your question with the database image and also did u test by putting the number of records we are getting in the variable?

Comment: Updated the post. Im not sure how I would do that, but the picture of the table is the result that this code gives me, with each cell being  a result from the loop @NaveenKN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var getPR = "SELECT kg, rep, date FROM Test WHERE exerVariName LIKE '%Comp%' AND exercise = @0 order by kg desc";
db.Execute(getPR, i);
var data = db.Query(getPR, i)

@for (var ii = 1; ii <= 12; ii++)
{
    var matched = data.SingleOrDefault(x => x.rep == ii);
    if (matched != null)
    {
        DateTime Date = get.Date;
        var finalDate = Date.ToString("MMM d, yyyy");
        var weight = matched.kg + "kg";
        var reps = "x " + matched.rep;

        <td class="prTableCell" title="@finalDate">@weight @reps</td>
    }
    else
    {
        <td class="prTableCell">0kg</td>
    }
}
```

You can execute sql query just one time and get all records based on exercise type. You don't need to query for repetition every time, it will be more efficient.

When in the loop use `Linq` to find record, which has 1 rep. If there will be no such record, il will return `null` and you will know that you need empty `td`. If record is found, then use its data to populate `td`.

Edit: even more, you can just query database just a single time like this

```
var getPR = "SELECT kg, rep, date, exercise FROM Test WHERE exerVariName LIKE '%Comp%' order by kg desc";
```

and change `Linq` to this

```
var matched = data.SingleOrDefault(x => x.exercise == i && x.rep == ii);
```

Comment: Well, the first version gave me error, and trying to translate the error it says something like `sequence contains more than one matching element` and after the edit you did it gives me, `cant use == for type int and string` refering to the `Linq` thing!

Comment: `singleordefault` means that there was more that one record in list where `rep = ii`. you can change that with `FirstOrDefault`, so it will not complain about being more records

Comment: Which line did it say about converting int to string?

Comment: `var matched = data.SingleOrDefault(x => x.exercise == i && x.rep == ii);` gave == error from int to string

Comment: someone is really happy :D

Comment: for sure man haha! However, may I bother you some more? I have one more problem that is basically the same for the rest of the exercise names, could I start a discussion chat with you if you got time? Thought I could solve it by myself with the code you provided but didn't manage to do that!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142170/discussion-between-mantas-cekanauskas-and-pontus-svedberg).